# WDS Disconnected! in console of Firefox Angular 7

Tags: angular

It appears WDS disconnected error in the console. but it doesn't appear in the chrome initially. but when I refresh the page it appears. I have updated webpack-dev-server upto 4.27. what are the solutions for this ?